# How do I add a library reference in vba so that it remains added every time I open a new workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

Forgive me, I'm still sort of new to this, but...

In vba within Excel, when I go to Tools - References I can add a reference and it works just fine.  The box stays checked everytime I reopen that workbook.

However, if I create a new workbook, I have to re-establish the reference to that same library.  How do I set this up so that the library reference I want remains checked all the time - at an Excel Application level as opposed to an Excel Workbook level?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow [these](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx) steps to Create a personal workbook.

Once you have created the workbook. Simply go to the VBA editor of the personal workbook and add the reference. Close all workbooks and now open a new one. You will see that the reference is already there.

In case the above link ever breaks. Here is a screenshot of that link.

[image]

Comment: You are very kind Peter :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to [use late binding instead of early binding](https://powerspreadsheets.com/send-email-excel-vba/) for my outlook objects setting. With late binding, my code became agnostic of the outlook reference libraries. Thus, the code could easily be used on any computer without checking the referenced libraries. This is much more convivial for making macros for unsavvy users.